# Make a binding on Tag property of ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following syntax and i would like to make a data binding on the Tag property of ComboboxItem. Is that possible?

```
  <ComboBox Name="LanguageCombo" VerticalAlignment="Center"
            SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" Margin="5,1,0,1"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:ToolsOptionsSettings.Default},Path=ToolsOptionsLanguage, Mode=TwoWay}" >
     <ComboBoxItem Tag="en-US" Content="{DynamicResource English}"></ComboBoxItem>
     <ComboBoxItem Tag="de-DE" Content="{DynamicResource German}"></ComboBoxItem>
     <ComboBoxItem Tag="ja-JP" Content="{DynamicResource Japanese}"></ComboBoxItem>
  </ComboBox>
```

ToolsOptionsLanguage - returns a string like en-US for example, which is the value of the Tag property.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, `Tag` is a `DependancyProperty` so it supports data binding.